# Disable next page of ViewPager Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, touch-event

I have a viewpager with four page. page1,page2,page3,page4.
I want to when at page2,view pager will not be next to page (page3),only previous to page1. How must I do !

Comment: what is the purpose of page3 and page4 if you don't navigate to them?

Comment: In some case, I also use page3 and page4. But is this case, I want to as my question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9141498/1318946

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the getCount() method in the PagerAdapter to achieve this.

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
ViewAdapter viewAdapter = new ViewAdapter();
viewAdapter.setCount(2);
viewPager.setAdapter(viewAdapter);


private class ViewAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    private int count = 4;
    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    //other methods
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Shashika, but don't forget to call **viewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()**.

Comment: Please [do *not* post comments in answer posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).