# ViewPager.setCurrentItem responsing NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

I have implemented ViewPager and fragment(say A, B, C, D, E) as an child.

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter); // FragmentStatePagerAdapter
```

after then I called `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(3, false);` which is giving NullPointerException. Following log:

> java.lang.NullPointerException E/AndroidRuntime(  330):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:116)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  330):  at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  330):  at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1048)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  330):  at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  330):  at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  330):  at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478) E/AndroidRuntime(  330):
>     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  330):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  330):  at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478) E/AndroidRuntime(  330):
>     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  330):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  330):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  330):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)

What I am guessing here is, might be PageViewer did not load page I am asking for, but I wait here also before to load, but it's same result.

Does any one have any suggestion for same.

**Edit:**
**Adapter class**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.


            switch (id) {
            case 0:

                fragment = new TestFragment1();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt("position", position + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);

                break;

            case 1:

                fragment = new TestFragment2();
                args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt("position", position + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);

                break;

            case 3:

                fragment = new TestFragment4();
                args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt("position", position + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);

                break;


            case 4:

                fragment = new TestFragment5();
                args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt("position", position + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);

                break;



            }

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return total_child_count;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and code to init pageviewer and set adapter:

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

and code to set request page:

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPosition, false);
```

Comment: not sure, but same if I set for setCurrentItem(1,...) then it work fine.

Comment: Share your complete code ,including adapter.

Comment: How many items in your adapter class?

Comment: anyway this question is offtopic ... `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.`

Comment: fragment at position 3 is null https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java#L116

Comment: @Selvin why this is so dear, it is required to understand why page viewer behaving like this.

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA it's 4-5 for now but it can increase...please check updated question.

Comment: @Shubh have you tried to return a new fragment for the index 2 in your getItem method?

Comment: @mikepenz yes...for every position I have written different fragment. I missed in code but that I have checked.

Comment: @Shubh did you solved the problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: @MarioVelasco share ur code ...might be I can help you.